# How do I use the 'useBodyParser' option on Nestjs

Tags: json, express, nestjs, body-parser

Property 'useBodyParser' does not exist on type 'NestExpressApplication'

I'm trying to use the useBodyParser option on the Nestjs app instance, however I keep getting the

> Property 'useBodyParser' does not exist on type 'NestExpressApplication'

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import type { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';

async function bootstrap() {

const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, {
rawBody: true,
});

app.useBodyParser('application/json', { bodyLimit });

await app.listen(3000);
  
}  

bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

upgrade `@nestjs/platform-express`, `@nestjs/common` and `@nestjs/core` packages.

Comment: Upgrade from 9.x to 10.x fails for peer dependencies problems

Comment: `useBodyParser` was added in nestjs 9.3.0